# Nodejs async & sync reading & writing of files - when to use which?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

It's a very general question, but I don't quite understand. When would I prefer one over the other? I don't seem to understand what situations might arise, which would *clearly* favour one over the other. Are there strong reasons to avoid x / use x?

Comment: The equally general answer: any sync operation blocks every other operation. A less general example: if you have a web server and read a file synchronously, no requests will be processed until that file is read. So: avoid blocking except for one-off things at startup, and avoid blocking on I/O especially since it takes a long and sometimes unpredictable amount of time.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes it much clearer, i.e., the example of the web server and incoming requests. I thought of an electron application with nodejs, which is simply reading a file and did not understand what difference that would make *really*, if my software really just has to wait for that file to load anyways. Thanks so much.

Comment: @GeorgeWelder: Ah, Electron. I've added a note to my answer to try to address that bit, but sadly my knowledge of Electron is minimal.

Answer (score 3):

> When would I prefer one over the other?

In a server intended to scale and serve the needs of many users, you would only use synchronous I/O during server initialization.  In fact, `require()` itself uses synchronous I/O.  In all other parts of your server that handle incoming requests once the server is already up and running, you would only use asynchronous I/O.

There are other uses for node.js besides creating a server.  For example, suppose you want to create a script that will parse through a giant file and look for certain words or phrases.  And, this script is designed to run by itself to process one file and it has no persistent server functionality and it has no particular reason to do I/O from multiple sources at once.  In that case, it's perfectly OK to use synchronous I/O.  For example, I created a node.js script that helps me age backup files (removing backup files that meet some particular age criteria) and my computer automatically runs that script once a day.  There was no reason to use asynchronous I/O for that type of use so I used synchronous I/O and it made the code simpler to write.

> I don't seem to understand what situations might arise, which would clearly favour one over the other. Are there strong reasons to avoid x / use x?

Avoid ever using synchronous I/O in the request handlers of a server.  Because of the single threaded nature of Javascript in node.js, using synchronous I/O blocks the node.js Javascript thread so it can only do one thing at a time (which is death for a multi-user server) whereas asynchronous I/O does not block the node.js Javascript thread (allowing it to potentially serve the needs of many users).

In non-multi-user situations (code that is only doing one thing for one user), synchronous I/O may be favored because writing the code is easier and there may be no advantages to using asynchronous I/O.

> I thought of an electron application with nodejs, which is simply reading a file and did not understand what difference that would make really, if my software really just has to wait for that file to load anyways.

If this is a single user application and there's nothing else for your application to be doing while waiting for the file to be read into memory (no sockets to be responding to, no screen updates, no other requests to be working on, no other file operations to be running in parallel), then there is no advantage to using asynchronous I/O so synchronous I/O will be just fine and likely a bit simpler to code.

Answer (score 2):

> When would I prefer one over the other?

Use the non-`Sync` versions (the async ones) unless there's literally nothing else you need your program to do while the I/O is pending, in which case the `Sync` ones are fine; see below for details...

> Are there strong reasons to avoid x / use x?

Yes. NodeJS runs your JavaScript code on a single thread. If you use the `Sync` version of an I/O function, that thread is blocked waiting on I/O and can't do anything else. If you use the async version, the I/O can continue in the background while the JavaScript thread gets on with other work; the I/O completion will be queued as a job for the JavaScript thread to come back to later.

If you're running a foreground Node app that doesn't need to do anything else while the I/O is pending, you're probably fine using `Sync` calls. But if you're using Node for processing multiple things at once (like web requests), best to use the async versions.

In a comment you added under the question you've said:

> I thought of an electron application with nodejs, which is simply reading a file and did not understand what difference that would make *really*, if my software really just has to wait for that file to load anyways.

I have virtually no knowledge of Electron, but I note that it uses a "main" process to manage windows and then a "rendering" process per window ([link](https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/)). That being the case, using `Sync` functions will block the relevant process, which may affect application or window responsiveness. But I don't have any deep knowledge of Electron (more's the pity).

---

Until somewhat recently, using async functions meant using lots of callback-heavy code which was hard to compose:

```
// (Obviously this is just an example, you wouldn't actually read and write a file this way, you'd use streaming...)
fs.readFile("file1.txt", function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        // Do something about the error...
    } else {
        fs.writeFile("file2.txt", data, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                // Do something about the error...
            } else {
                // All good
        });
    }
});
```

Then promises came along and if you used a promisified* version of the operation (shown here with pseudonyms like `fs.promisifiedXYZ`), it still involved callbacks, but they were more composable:

```
// (See earlier caveat, just an example)
fs.promisifiedReadFile("file1.txt")
.then(function(data) {
    return fs.promisifiedWriteFile("file2.txt", data);
})
.then(function() {
    // All good
})
.catch(function(err) {
    // Do something about the error...
});
```

Now, in recent versions of Node, you can use the ES2017+ `async`/`await` syntax to write synchronous-looking code that is, in fact, asynchronous:

```
// (See earlier caveat, just an example)
(async () => {
    try {
        const data = await fs.promisifiedReadFile("file1.txt");
        fs.promisifiedWriteFile("file2.txt", data);
        // All good
    } catch (err) {
        // Do something about the error...
    }
})();
```

---

Node's API predates promises and has its own conventions. There are various libraries out there to help you "promisify" a Node-style callback API so that it uses promises instead. One is [`promisify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promisify) but there are others.